# Use npm module in Grunt registerTask

Tags: npm, gruntjs

I would like use npm module on new tasks, but i've no result :

```
  grunt.registerTask('done', function () {

    var prepend = require('prepend');

    var file = 'app.bundleES6.js',
        string = '// My string';

    prepend(file, string, function(error) {
      if (error)
        console.error(error.message);
      else
        console.log('Yeah');
    });

  });
```

When i run `grunt done`, i'm not see console.log, just :

```
Running "done" task

Done, without errors.
```

Do you know how i can use npm module on Grunt registerTask ?

Thank you !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with your task is that it's asynchronous.

You can register asynchronous Grunt tasks, but you have to call `this.async()` to obtain the completion callback and you have to call the callback, when your task is complete (passing `false` if the task has failed).

Like this:

```
grunt.registerTask('done', function () {

  var callback = this.async();
  var prepend = require('prepend');

  var file = 'app.bundleES6.js',
      string = '// My string';

  prepend(file, string, function(error) {
    if (error) {
      console.error(error.message);
      callback(false);
    }
    else {
      console.log('Yeah');
      callback();
    }
  });
});
```